# Map Nested Object Key To Another Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Working with the following object, how can the `roles` => `name` be added to the `sites` => `userPermission` object with the matching `roleId`?

For example, the `userPermission` key of the first `sites` entry would be updated to:

```
 "userPermission": {
   "roleId": 6,
   "roleName": "Field Representative"
 }
```

Once the `roleName` key has been mapped, there is no longer a need for the `roles` array and it can be removed from the end result as shown in the expected outcome.

```
const obj = {
  "id": 542,
  "createdAt": "2018-12-06T22:34:12.553Z",
  "sites": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "siteId": "sixtysixone",
      "edition": "pro",
      "userPermission": {
        "roleId": 6
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "siteId": "amplify",
      "edition": "pro",
      "userPermission": {
        "roleId": 4
      }
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Field Representative"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Program Manager"
    }
  ]
};
```

Expected outcome:

```
const outcome = {
  "id": 542,
  "createdAt": "2018-12-06T22:34:12.553Z",
  "sites": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "siteId": "sixtysixone",
      "edition": "pro",
      "userPermission": {
        "roleId": 6,
        "roleName": "Field Representative"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "siteId": "amplify",
      "edition": "pro",
      "userPermission": {
        "roleId": 4
        "roleName": "Program Manager"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I have attempted with a combination of `.map` and `.find`, but feel there is a much more simple/readable way to accomplish this.

```
const outcome = obj.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  sites: o.sites
    .map(s => ({
      ...s,
      roleName: o.roles
        .find(r => r.id === s.roleId).name,
   })),
}));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: I don't think you can `map` an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a map of roles:

```
 const roles = new Map(obj.roles.map(({ id, name }) => [id, { roleId: id, roleName: name }]));
```

Then you can just look up:

```
const outcome = {
  ...obj,
  sites: obj.sites.map(site => ({ 
    ...site,
    userPermission: roles.get(site.userPermission.roleId),
  }),
  roles: undefined,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the `sites` and update the `userPermission` using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

(This assumes that every `roleId` exists in `roles`. Otherwise, you need to check if `find` returns `undefined` first)

```js
const obj = {"id":542,"createdAt":"2018-12-06T22:34:12.553Z","sites":[{"id":10,"siteId":"sixtysixone","edition":"pro","userPermission":{"roleId":6}},{"id":2,"siteId":"amplify","edition":"pro","userPermission":{"roleId":4}}],"roles":[{"id":6,"name":"Field Representative"},{"id":4,"name":"Program Manager"}]};

obj.sites.forEach(site => {
  site.userPermission.roleName = 
        obj.roles.find(r => r.id === site.userPermission.roleId).name
})

delete obj.roles;
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first turn the `roles` array into an object to ease the retrieval of the role names:

```
let rolesMap = obj.roles.reduce((acc, role) =>
    (acc[role.id] = role.name, acc),
    Object.create(null)
);
```

Then just loop over the sites array, adding the `roleName` property to each site `userPermission` object by fetching the value from `rolesMap`:

```
obj.sites.forEach(site => {
    if(rolesMap[site.userPermission.roleId]) {
        site.userPermission.roleName = rolesMap[site.userPermission.roleId];
    }
});
```

You can skip the `if` test if you know for sure that each site object will have an associated role object in the `roles` array. And if you want to create a new `sites` object then use `map` instead of `forEach`.

And finally you can `delete` the `roles` property if you want:

```
delete obj.roles;
```

**Example:**

```js
const obj = {"id":542,"createdAt":"2018-12-06T22:34:12.553Z","sites":[{"id":10,"siteId":"sixtysixone","edition":"pro","userPermission":{"roleId":6}},{"id":2,"siteId":"amplify","edition":"pro","userPermission":{"roleId":4}}],"roles":[{"id":6,"name":"Field Representative"},{"id":4,"name":"Program Manager"}]};

let rolesMap = obj.roles.reduce((acc, role) =>
    (acc[role.id] = role.name, acc),
    Object.create(null)
);

obj.sites.forEach(site => {
    if(rolesMap[site.userPermission.roleId]) {
        site.userPermission.roleName = rolesMap[site.userPermission.roleId];
    }
});

delete obj.roles;

console.log(obj);
```